# How to add attachment in nebular chat UI?

Tags: angular, nebular

I am working on nebular chat UI but its working for sending and retrieve text messages  and I am also sending the attachment its also working but I wont be able to display it in my chat UI box.
    html

```
        <nb-chat-message *ngFor="let msg of messages"
                             [type]="msg.Type"
                             [message]="msg.Message"
                             [reply]="msg.Reply"
                             [sender]="msg.FullName"
                             [files]="chatFiles"
                             [quote]="msg.quote"
                             >
            </nb-chat-message>
```

````
 ```
    getComment(ContentID: string) {
        this.item = new ChatMessage();
        this.chatShowcaseService.getComments(ContentID).subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.comments = data;
          this.messages = this.comments.Data;
           console.log(JSON.stringify(this.messages) +'messages');
          for (let i = 0; i < this.comments.Data.length; i++) {
            this.item.CreatedDate = this.comments.Data[i].CreatedDate;
            this.item.Message = this.comments.Data[i].Message;
            this.item.Type = this.comments.Data[i].Type;
            this.item.Sender = this.comments.Data[i].CreatedBy.FullName;
            this.item.Reply = this.comments.Data[i].Reply;
            this.item.Quote = this.comments.Data[i].Quote;

            if (
              this.comments.Data[i].Attachments != null &&
              this.comments.Data[i].Attachments.length > 0
            ) {

              for (let j = 0; j < this.comments.Data[i].Attachments.length; j++) {
                const chat = new ChatFile();
                chat.url = this.comments.Data[i].Attachments[j].ExternalLink;

                chat.type = 'image/jpeg';
                this.chatFiles.push(chat);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
```
````

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: `[files]="chatFiles"` must be `[files]="msg.chatFiles"`, its for inside for `this.item.files = this.chatFiles`